# iOS6 Maps performance issue

Tags: ios, performance, maps, mkmapview

On iPhone4s/iPad2, apps using a fullsize MKMapView exhibit a **much worse scrolling performance** than in the stock Maps app. Especially on fast scroll gestures it lags very bad.

It seems that loading the vectors/tiles needs much time. When I test it with satellite maps it runs smoothly (so issue just comes up in vector based map).

**I verified this issue:**

- in own apps and Instagram (Map feature)
- on iPhone4s and iPad2

On my iPad there was iOS 5 still running. I checked in iOS5 my App's map + Instagram's map and both were smoothly. After that I updated it to 6.0.1 and both maps of the apps were lagging.

**How to reproduce?**

- create a view based iPhone Application in Xcode
- add a mapview to the generated xib (fullscreen)
- launch it on your device an scroll very fast

**How I did work around it:**

I set the map to satellite type and overlay it with OSM vectors (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_in_MapKit). That runs smoothly but needs double traffic (for satellite pictures and osm vectors)

**I don't like this workaround, so does anybody noticed this issue?**

Update: I filled a bug with the Apple Bug reporter - ID:**12638328** feel free to participate

Comment: I have noticed this issue, especially with <A6 processors.

Comment: what happens when testing on iPhone 5?? I am having the same issue with my iPhone4s. I don't have my 5 yet.